# $('#' + postFormId ).html( xml ) throwing Unexpected call to method error

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, netsuite

Edit:I have tried jquery versions 1.11.3 and 1.4.2

The following code throws the error "Unexpected call to method or property access" when emulating previous versions of ie(5 and 7). Using this emulation is not optional as it is set by a third party IT. It works fine in IE8 and there was a version that was essentially the same code (I copy and pasted it, and made a couple of changes) used to work in 5 and 7.

Using console.logs, I'm fairly certain  that the issue is in $('#' + postFormId ).html( xml ) though I could be wrong.

```
if( punchOutCartPage != "SalesOrder" ) {
    $(document).on('click','#btn-proceed-checkout',function(){
        var itemsXML = parseShoppingCart();
        var headerXML = "\t<header>\n\t\t{sellerId}\n\t\t{buyerID}\n\t\t{sessionId}\n\t</header>";

        var shoppingCartXML = createNetSuiteShoppingCart( headerXML, itemsXML );
        var form = $("#cart");
        var form_action = form.attr("action");                  

        $.ajax({
            url:'/app/site/backend/emptycart.nl?c=',
            context: document.body,
            success: function(data){
                var form_serialized = form.serialize(); 
                $.post(form_action, form_serialized,
                    function (val) {
                        postToPunchOutUrl(punchOutUserCartUrl, shoppingCartXML);    
                    }
                );
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
} 
function parseShoppingCart() {

}

function createNetSuiteShoppingCart( headerXML, itemsXML ) {    
    var parentCompany =localStorage.StrparentCompany;
    var account =localStorage.Straccount;
    var sessionId = localStorage.StrpunchOutSessionId;

    headerXML = headerXML.replace("{sellerId}", "<sellerID>" + encodeXML(account) + "</sellerID>");
    headerXML = headerXML.replace("{buyerID}", "<buyerID>" + encodeXML(parentCompany) + "</buyerID>");
    headerXML = headerXML.replace("{sessionId}", "<PunchOutSessionID>" + encodeXML(sessionId) + "</PunchOutSessionID>");
    itemsXML = "<NetSuiteSellerPunchOutShoppingCart>\n" + headerXML + "\n" + "<itemList>\n" + fezzik + "</itemList>\n" + "</NetSuiteSellerPunchOutShoppingCart>";
    itemsXML = encodeXML(itemsXML);

    var shoppingCartXML = '<input type="hidden" name="shoppingcart-urlencoded" value="{url-encoded-raw-xml}">';
    return shoppingCartXML.replace("{url-encoded-raw-xml}", itemsXML);
}

function postToPunchOutUrl( url, xml ) {
    var postFormId = "poomform";
    $('#' + postFormId ).html( xml );
    $('#' + postFormId ).attr( "action", url );
    document.forms[postFormId].submit();
}

function encodeXML(string) {
    return string.replace(/\&/g, '&' + 'amp;').replace(/</g, '&' + 'lt;').replace(/>/g, '&' + 'gt;').replace(/\'/g, '&' + 'apos;').replace(/\"/g, '&' + 'quot;');
}
```

Comment: share in JSfiddle your short code version.

Comment: What version of jQuery? if you're going to support IE5-8, you'll have to use a pretty old version, and then you'll have compatibility issues with IE9-11 and edge, and possibly some of the other modern browsers.

Comment: Even Microsoft doesn't support those versions of IE any more. As Kevin said, you're not going to have fun trying to use jquery AND support every version of IE out there with the same code. You might want to use conditional comments and use old school, DOM javascript for jquery fallback for older IE versions.

Comment: Believe me, if the users browser was in my control it would be modernized in a second. There are a TON of issues due to their browser versions (and yes I will have to support both modern and old) but for right now this is the one that I cant figure out, and that really needs fixed.

Comment: Where is `punchOutUserCartUrl` coming from?

Comment: , punchOutUserCartUrl =localStorage.StrpunchOutUserCartUrl and that storage contains an address as a string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was caused by the document mode emulation itself.  When internet explorer emulates document mode 5 or 7, it wraps a form  tag around your forms in certain cases. So this `<form method="POST" name="poomform" id="poomform" action="https://www.example.net"></form>` became (I didnt copy it, but approximately)

```
<form><form method="POST" name="poomform" id="poomform" action="https://www.example.net"></form></form>
```

Which then throws the unexpected call to method error.

I worked around this by adding the form with javascript after the page had loaded, so I replaced the form in the html with `<div id="poomformholder"></div>`

and then added a line of jquery to my postToPunchOutUrl function to look like:

```
function postToPunchOutUrl( url, xml ) {
    $('#' + "poomformholder" ).html("<form method=\"POST\" name=\"poomform\" id=\"poomform\" action=\"https://www.example.net\"></form>");
        //The id name of our form.
        var postFormId = "poomform";
                $('#' + postFormId ).attr("action",url);
        $('#' + postFormId ).html(xml);
```

And now everything works.  Hopefully this helps someone in the future and thank you for your help!